# Recursive matrix multiplication strassen algorithm

Tags: matrices, algorithms

I am having a hard time doing 4x4 matrix multiplication using strassen's algorithm. First I computed the product of two 4x4 matrices using default matrix multiplication (https://matrixcalc.org)

[image]

I now want to use strassen's method which I learned as follows:

[image]

I split the 4x4 matrix in 4 2x2 matrices first and calculate the products like in the image above:

[image]

When I put the parts back together I get a different result compared to the default multiplication. Can anyone point out what I am doing wrong?

Corrected computation:

[image]

Comment: Did you get the expected answer after correcting your calculation?

Comment: @user490892 yes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check your computation of $P_2$.

When computing $P_2$, instead of adding $A$ to $B$ to get $A+B$, you multiple $A$ and $B$ and get $A*B$ which is incorrect.

Comment: I corrected that, however it still does not give me the correct result. Apart from what you pointed out, do you see anything else I am doing wrong?

Comment: Your computation of $AE+BG$. The formula is $P5+P4-P2+P6$. You have computed $P5+P4-P2-P6$ instead.

Comment: Also, there is another mistakes at the last line of your computation. Can you spot it?

Comment: In general, $-a+b=b-a$. Also, $-a-b=-(a+b). $

Answer (score 1):

When computing $P_2$, instead of adding $A$ to $B$ to get $A+B$, you multiple $A$ and $B$ and get $A*B$ which is incorrect.